# Mongoose Invalid value for schema path

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, require

I am getting the following error for an embedded schema.

throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema path `' + prefix + key + '`');
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `disciplinedata.type`

disciplineinstance.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { disciplineSchema } = require('../models/discipline');
const { majorTaskInstanceSchema } = require('./majortaskinstance');
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

const disciplineInstanceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  estimateEffortunits: {type: Number, default: 0 },
  disciplineInstancename: {type: String, default: ''},
  majortasks: {type: [majorTaskInstanceSchema], default: [] },
  disciplinedata: {type: disciplineSchema }
});

module.exports.disciplineInstanceSchema = disciplineInstanceSchema;
module.exports.DisciplineInstance = mongoose.model('DisciplineInstance', disciplineInstanceSchema);
```

and discipline.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

const disciplineSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  majortasklist: { type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'MajorTask'},
  disciplinename: { type: String },
  disciplineunitname: { type: String },
});

module.exports.disciplineSchema = disciplineSchema;
module.exports = mongoose.model('Discipline', disciplineSchema);
module.exports.Discipline = mongoose.model('Discipline', disciplineSchema);
```

I have tried a range of things to fix this issue. It must have to do with an error in discipline.js, but I can't find the error. The types seem fine and i can't work out any issue with the actual require.